# Child node attribute in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to access child node attributes in **xsl:if**

I have to convert that Xml to text file

```
<Report>
<Total>
    <RecordValues>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="1" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="dtrk_sysid" fieldValue="0"/>
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="100" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="tester" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-10-18 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Menu" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission X" />
        </Record>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="2" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="dtrk_sysid" fieldValue="55555"/>
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="100" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="user1" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-12-15 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Control" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission E" />
        </Record>
        <Record>
        <FieldValue fieldName="index"       fieldValue="3" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="dtrk_sysid" fieldValue="55555"/>
        <FieldValue fieldName="version"     fieldValue="15" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="user"        fieldValue="user2" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="date_modified"   fieldValue="2010-10-02 12:18:12" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="object_name"     fieldValue="Run" />
        <FieldValue fieldName="permission"  fieldValue="Permission R" />
        </Record>
    </RecordValues>
</Total>
```

I already know how to do that, but the file must have header record which is should appear only once as the first record of the file. It must contains some default values and some values from **FieldValue**  node.
Here is the example of header record:

```
HDRTT55555EE000KK20101018UU
1 100  101810
tester  Menu       Permission X
2 100  121510
user1   Control    Permission E
3 15   100210
user2   Run        Permission R
```

Here is what I've done so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-   declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Report/Total/RecordValues"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Report/Total/RecordValues/Record/FieldValue"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="RecordValues">
    <xsl:text>HDR</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>TT</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="fvsys" select="Record/FieldValue[@fieldName = 'dtrk_sysid']"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$fvsys/@fieldValue != '0'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fvsys/@fieldValue"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>12343</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>EE</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>KK</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="Record/FieldValue[@fieldName='date_modified']">
        <xsl:call-template name="ppad">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="concat(substring(translate(Record/FieldValue[@fieldName = 'date_modified']/@fieldValue,'-',''),5,4), substring(Record/FieldValue[@fieldName = 'date_modified']/@fieldValue,3,2))"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="len" select="6"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>UU</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FieldValue">

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ppad">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="chr" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:param name="len" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &lt; $len">
            <xsl:call-template name="ppad">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="concat($str, $chr)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="len" select="$len"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="chr" select="$chr"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes.  Please provide more details, such as a sample XML document and what you've tried so far.

Comment: please provide the full desired output.

Comment: This is not clear at all. First, tipical header/data handle in XSLT involves the use of modes. Second, you are performing some existencial comparison over all the records: "is there **any** `@fieldName` equal to 'dtrk_sysid' and **any** `@fieldValue` not equal to 0?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with the following if statement:

```
<xsl:if test="Record/FieldValue/@fieldName='dtrk_sysid' and Record/FieldValue/@fieldValue!='0'">
    <xsl:value-of select="Record/FieldValue/@fieldValue"/>
</xsl:if>
```

is that the @fieldValue you're trying to compare after the `and` is supposed to be the @fieldValue of the `<FieldValue>` whose @fieldName is 'dtrk_sysid', but there is nothing that limits the second comparison to that particular `<FieldValue>`. The `<xsl:if test=...>` does not set a context. `<xsl:value-of>` will then select the **first** @fieldValue attribute of all Record/FieldValue nodes under the context node, which by luck happens to be the right one, in your sample input XML (but maybe not always?).

To fix that, you can capture the context (the `<FieldValue>` whose @fieldName is 'dtrk_sysid') in a variable:

```
  <xsl:variable name="fvsys" select="(Record/FieldValue[@fieldName = 'dtrk_sysid'])[1]"/>
```

Then you can replace your first two if statements with:

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$fvsys/@fieldValue != '0'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$fvsys/@fieldValue"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>12343</xsl:text>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

(The above has been modified to fit the behavior described in comments.)

You can replace your third if statement with:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="(Record/FieldValue[@fieldName = 'date_modified'])[1]/@fieldValue"/>
```

This will not output anything if no such FieldValue exists.

If after this you're still not getting the desired output, tell us what output you are getting, and how it differs from the desired output.

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks for helping me. Sorry for late respond, was away from computer. I just run test. Condition in WHEN statement not working correctly. If <FieldValue fieldName="dtrk_sysid" fieldValue="55555"/> it returns "55555", but if fieldValue="0" it return "0". So it doesn't go to default.

Comment: @klipa, try changing `!= 0` back  to `!= '0'`, like you originally had.

Comment: @klipa: can you edit to show your updated XSLT that has the result you just mentioned?

Comment: @LarsH, I updated XML and XSLT. Actually "dtrk_sysid" exists in each Record and not on the first position. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @klipa, ok, I understand now why it's not working. But I'm not sure what the correct behavior should be on the above input. If there are n different records, and several of them have a dtrk_sysid fieldValue attribute that is not "0", which one do you want to output? I'll edit my answer so that it outputs the first non-zero one, but I don't know if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: @klipa - a similar problem will happen with the 'date_modified' FieldValue... since every Record has one, we are selecting multiple FieldValues. `translate()` and `substring()` will each take the first one. Is that what you want?

Comment: @LarsH: Those values should be taking from the first Record, because they will be the same in each Record. I just change to "0" in the first only for test purpose.

Comment: @klipa: ok, so the way my answer shows now, with the modified `<xsl:value-of select="$fvsys/@fieldValue[. != '0']">`, should work correctly for you. If it doesn't, let me know...

Comment: @klipa: ok. For better maintainability, I would put `[1]` at the end of each of those select XPaths to make it easier to see that each one is using the first of potentially several nodes that might match the expression. I'll edit my answer accordingly. (Don't forget to Accept it if it solved your problem! :-)

Comment: @LarsH: I'm sorry, didn't look closely, but now if it "0" it picking value from the second Record "55555' instead of default "12343"

Comment: @klipa: in what case should it use the default value: if the *first* dtrk_sysid field is "0"? If *any* dtrk_sysid field is "0"?

Comment: ok, I edited my answer to modify both the definition of the fvsys variable, and how it is used in the when/value-of.

Comment: @LarsH: Now looks fine. Thanks again! :)